# Android Studio Make Buttons Disappear From ScrollView

Tags: android, button, scrollview

I have a ScrollView that contains a lot of buttons.
I want to create a search bar, so how can I disappear a button from the ScrollView so he will be hidden and the ScrollView will get shorter?
and then ofcourse I want to be able to return the button to the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the visibility of the button from the activity by

```
if(true){
   btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
   btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
};
```

you may also have to change the visibility in XML also

```
<ButtonView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: commend if it works